# android widget as async task

Tags: android, android-asynctask

sorry for question which was many time answered but for me is still now working :-(

I have following activiy code:

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    final int count = appWidgetIds.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int widgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.simple_widget);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SimpleWidgetProvider.class);
        intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        new Weather(remoteViews).execute();
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.actionButton, pendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
    }
}
```

}

with Async Weather class but this doesn't work. Value is missing in remoteViews.

```
class Weather extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {

private RemoteViews remoteViews ;

public Weather(RemoteViews remoteViews) {
    this.remoteViews = remoteViews;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
  return "COLD";
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String temp) {
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textView, temp);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever `RemoteViews` that you pass to `updateAppWidget()` will be used *at that time*. In your case, your `Weather` task will not even *begin* to be executed by the time that the `RemoteViews` has been used, and so your change to that `RemoteViews` will be pointless.

Instead:

- Switch to `Thread`, as there is no value in using `AsyncTask` here, and
- Do all the work for a given widget ID, including calling `updateAppWidget()`, in the `Thread`